# Python how to import mod2

Tags: python, flask, module

Summary:
My goal: working on upload from mod1.py. I expect the uploaded file at    /static/img/. However, there is nothing happens when tried

I have never done this procedure before. What I want is to be able to import and reuse function from mod2 in mod1. The mod1 is main. Both modules are in a same root folder. I don't use django. I put an empty **init**.py on the same directory. Please help suggest a specific ideas relate to mod2.

**the structure**

```
root/
    __init__.py

    mod1.py

    mod2.py
```

**mod1 (a working .py):**

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template, request, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True

comments = []

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("main_page.html", comments=comments)

    comments.append(request.form["contents"])
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

**mod2 (a working .py):**

```
import os
#from flask import Flask, flash, request, redirect, url_for
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, request, url_for

from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from flask import Request
from flask_uploads import IMAGES, UploadSet, configure_uploads



UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'uploads'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = {'txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'docx'}

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 16 * 1024 * 1024


photos = UploadSet("photos", IMAGES)
app.config["UPLOADED_PHOTOS_DEST"] = "static/img"
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = os.urandom(24)
configure_uploads(app, photos)


def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'photo' in request.files:
        photos.save(request.files['photo'])
        flash("Photo saved successfully.")
        return render_template('upload.html')
    return render_template('upload.html')


from flask import send_from_directory

@app.route('/uploads/<filename>')
def uploaded_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)


from werkzeug.middleware.shared_data import SharedDataMiddleware
app.add_url_rule('/uploads/<filename>', 'uploaded_file', build_only=True)
app.wsgi_app = SharedDataMiddleware(app.wsgi_app, {
    '/uploads':  app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']
})
```

**What I tried on mod1:**

```
import os
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, request, url_for

from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from flask import Request
from flask_uploads import IMAGES, UploadSet, configure_uploads

from mod1 import getPhotos
from mod1 import upload

UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'uploads'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = {'txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'docx'}

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 16 * 1024 * 1024

photos = getPhotos()

app.config["UPLOADED_PHOTOS_DEST"] = "static/img"
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = os.urandom(24)
configure_uploads(app, photos)

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

upload()

"""
#as a function
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'photo' in request.files:
        photos.save(request.files['photo'])
        flash("Photo saved successfully.")
        return render_template('upload.html')
    return render_template('upload.html')
"""
from flask import send_from_directory
@app.route('/uploads/<filename>')
def uploaded_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)

from werkzeug.middleware.shared_data import SharedDataMiddleware
app.add_url_rule('/uploads/<filename>', 'uploaded_file', build_only=True)
app.wsgi_app = SharedDataMiddleware(app.wsgi_app, {
    '/uploads':  app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']
})
```

There is no error. When I open the /static/img, nothing happens. My research on these pages are not solved:
[What is __init__.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for)
And https://realpython.com/python-modules-packages/

Am I in the right direction? What are your suggestions?
Thank you very much for your specific suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to import variables from mod2 which is not possible, you might want to turn that into a function like this:

```
photos = UploadSet("photos", IMAGES)
def getPhotos(photos = photos):
    return(photos)
```

Then you can import the getPhotos function and use it like so:

```
from mod2 import getPhotos
photos = getPhotos()
```

Instead of importing UploadSet and configure_uploads from mod2, import them from flask.

```
from flask_uploads import UploadSet, configure_uploads
```

Comment: mepro, it works after applying your codes. The above code, **what I tried on mod1**, has been edited to a working one. In addition to edit the codes, I altered the wsgi.py file in pythonanywhere to **from mod2 import app as application**. Thank you so much for this valuable point. At this moment I can't rate your post, not enough point. I will come back.

Comment: Also, I added your function in mod2 for it to work:  **photos = UploadSet("photos", IMAGES)
def getPhotos(photos = photos):
    return(photos)**

Comment: I am glad it works for you and that I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I don't see where you've tried to import mod2 in mod1. But python, allows relative imports. For your case `from .mod2 import xxx` should work.

If you want to compose your you Flask application, you should not create an app in each file, but instead [blueprints](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/blueprints/), and register those in your single Flask app.

Comment: I am sorry. The above codes "**what I tried on mod1**" have been edited to "from mod2 import ..." Thank you for your comment. Did you mean only use one  app = Flask(__name__) in mod2.py ?

Comment: Over your entire app, `mod1`, `mod2`, etc, there should be a single `app = Flask(__name__)`, then you can register blueprints with this app.

Comment: nice. This is the first point I learn about import. I will consider blueprint for the next. Thanks again